# Generators of the Diffeomorphism Group

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, group-theory, lie-algebra, vector-fields

So what *are* the generators of a Diffeomorphism Group?

For simplicity, let's consider $ Diff(R^2) $ (diffeomorphisms of the euclidean plane.)

Diffeomorphisms are differentiable, invertible transformations (right?) So $Diff(R^2)$ would be a group made of all the differentiable, invertible functions on $R^2$, correct?

What would the generators be, then? All I can think of would be $x_1^i, x_2^j$ and $x_1^k*x_2^l$ so that you could build up your functions in a sort of power series fashion. ($x_1$ and $x_2$ being your $R^2$ coordinates.)

Yes, I know that Wikipedia says that the generators are

$L_h=h^\mu(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}$,

but what the heck is $h$ then? Any arbitrary function?

Comment: Your question is [easily answered by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Lie_algebra).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of an infinitesimal Diff as of a translation where the the shift is space dependent, $x^\mu\rightarrow x^\mu+\epsilon^\mu(x)$. Now, you get that the generators are $L_\epsilon=\epsilon^\nu(x)\partial_\nu$ since $L_\epsilon x^\mu=\epsilon^\mu(x)$. They form an infinite space since $\epsilon^\mu(x)$ is a function that can be expanded in infinitely many constant parameters given by the derivative of $\epsilon$ in zero, $\epsilon^\mu(x)=\sum_n x^{\nu_1}\cdot x^{\nu_n} \partial^n_{\nu_1\ldots \nu_n}\epsilon^\mu(x=0)/n!$. So a basis of generators would be
$$
L_\nu= \partial_\nu \,,\qquad L^{\mu_1}_\nu=x^{\mu_1} \partial_\nu \,,\qquad L^{\mu_1\mu_2}_\nu=x^{\mu_1}x^{\mu_2} \partial_\nu\,,\qquad \ldots
$$
where one recognizes some generators of various finite dimensional subgroups ($L_\mu$ generates translations, $L^\mu_\mu$ generates scale transformations, $L^{\mu}_\nu-L^{\nu}_\mu$ generates rotations,...)

Answer (score 2):

Formally speaking, given a [(differentiable, finite dimensional) manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifoldmanifold) $M$, then the (infinite dimensional) [Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) of [(globally defined) diffeomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism) (with composition $\circ$ as group structure) has the set $\Gamma(TM)$ of [(globally defined, differentiable) vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) as corresponding [Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra).

This (infinite dimensional) Lie algebra $\Gamma(TM)$ is endowed with the usual [Lie bracket of vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields) $[\cdot,\cdot]$. [(Basis)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29) elements for a Lie algebra are often called *generators.*

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Qmechanic's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/138578/26076) and [TwoBs's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/138607/26076) and answer "....what the heck is h then? Any arbitrary function?": $h$ is pretty much arbitrary. It is wontedly taken to be at least differentiability class $C^1$ (all first derivatives continuous) so that the Lie bracket of vector fields is defined as in Qmechanic's answer. You need to assume it is of class $C^\infty$ ("smooth", *i.e* derivatives of all orders exist) to kit $\Gamma(TM)$ (notation as in Qmechanic's answer) with the basis that TwoBs's answer defined for you. The exact conditions depend on the application, but $C^2$ will get you the ability to define the curvature tensor properly, and therefore to make the Einstein field equations meaningful in GTR, for example.